# Web development for iPads - do you need a Mac

Tags: ipad, web-applications, web

I have a project coming up which is focused on making a large amount of legacy code (classic asp and .NET webforms) iPad compatible, and was wondering whether or not I would need to do this on a Mac seeing as I cannot get the most up to date Safari browsers on a windows machine.  The code in question works in Chrome, Firefox and IE (6-10) so wouldn't need that much tweaking to make it work in an iPad.

FYI I have access to an iPad for testing.  I also have done some research online and on top of my experience I recon you can just develop to web standards and it should work fine on an iPad.

Basically I want to know if it's worth me getting a Mac to do this, or whether it would be a bit of a waist which is my hunch.

Answer (score 0):

You pretty much need to use Xcode to build the app, which is a mac only software. So yes, you will need a mac.

Comment: Do you not need Xcode for native app support, not a web app?  Also there appears to be a work around for Xcode windows support - http://maconwindows.blogspot.co.uk/

Comment: Well I guess if you can get mac to run on windows that would work for you. But dont expect to just copy your code over and it work. The code to write those apps is completely different from what you have already. You have to build it from scratch.